# Iterate and print content of groovy closures

Tags: groovy, closures

In a loop I create 4 closures and add them to a list:

```
closureList = []
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    def cl = {
        def A=i;
    }
    closureList.add(cl)
}
closureList.each() {print  it.call()println "";};
```

This results in the following output:

```
4
4
4
4
```

But I would have expected 0,1,2,3 instead. Why does the 4 closures have the same value for A?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, [this catches people out](https://dev.to/taikedz/gruelling-groovy-gotchas-loops-closures-and-jenkins-dsls-9pe), the free variable `i` is getting bound to the last value in the for loop, not the value at the time the closure was created.

You can either, change the loop into a closure based call:

```
closureList = (0..<4).collect { i ->
    { ->
        def a = i
    }
}
closureList.each { println  it() }
```

Or create an extra variable that gets re-set every time round the loop, and use that:

```
closureList = []

for( i in (0..<4) ) {
    int j = i
    closureList << { ->
        def a = j
    }
}
closureList.each { println  it() }
```

In both of these variants the variable closed by the closure is created afresh each time round the loop, so you get the result you'd expect