# Jenkins groovy for loops behaving differently

Tags: jenkins, groovy

My jenkins job looks like this:

```
class Device {
    String name
    Device(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}


class globals {
    static List<Device> devices = new ArrayList<Device>()
}

pipeline {    
    stages {
        stage('test for loop') {
            steps {
                script {
                    addDevices()
                    def testStages = [:]
                    echo "TESTING REGULAR LOOP"
                    for(index=0; index < globals.devices.size(); index++) {
                        Device device = globals.devices.get(index)
                        echo "BEFORE TEST STAGES $device.name" //shows correct name
                        testStages["$device.name"] = { //correct name here
                            echo "INSIDE TEST STAGE $device.name" //works correctly
                        }
                    }
                    parallel testStages
                }
            }
        }
        stage('test for each loop') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def testStages = [:]
                    echo "TESTING FOR EACH LOOP"
                    for(Device device: globals.devices) {
                        echo "BEFORE $device.name" //shows correct name
                        testStages["$device.name"] = { //correct name here
                            echo "INSIDE TESTSTAGES: $device.name" //device name is always the last name in the list.
                        }
                    }
                    parallel testStages
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void addDevices() {
    globals.devices.add(new Device("a"))
    globals.devices.add(new Device("b"))
}
```

The first loop works fine, it's a different device.name every time. However the second loop does not work, it prints the last item in the list. I really don't understand why. Would be really greatful if anyone can provide some insight.

Comment: even more interestingly: the label of the parallel steps are correct only within the closure it's wrong

Comment: @smelm indeed, i'm having a very hard time understanding what is wrong.

Comment: this should answer the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283443/for-loop-works-different-in-groovy-and-java

Comment: and also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145763/iterate-and-print-content-of-groovy-closures

Answer (score 0):

The core of the problem is this:

```
int x = 1
def cls = { y -> x + y }

x = 2

println cls(3)
```

Output:

```
5
```

So the closure changes when the variable x changes. If you are using a normal for loop or the `each` method, every iteration creates a new instance of the variable (device in you case), but since the for-each loop uses iterators internally, the same variable is reused which is then used in the created closures. So only the last value of device counts in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't quite follow what was said in the links you posted. Could you perhaps expand upon what makes the for each loop repeat the same value?