# Groovy for loop not incrementing correctly

Tags: for-loop, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am writing a jenkins pipeline with what is a mixture of declarative and scripted syntax.  I want to loop 4 times to create 4 parallel stages in the pipeline.  I want to capture what loop I'm on, and print that at the beggining of each step:

```java
def parallelStages = [:]

int cypressRunners = 4

for (int i = 1; i <= cypressRunners; i++) {
    parallelStages["Cypress ${i}"] = {
        stage("Cypress ${i}") { 
            node("cypress-runner-agent") {
                echo "------------------ Cypress ${i} Stage ------------------"
                // more steps
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the jenkins log, I always get a printout of

```
------------------ Runner 5 Stage ------------------
```

Even though in the left side, where the stage names are listed, I get the correctly indexed names of `Cypress 1`, `Cypress 2`, `Cypress 3`, `Cypress 4`, like this:

[image]

I am not a java or groovy developer, but this seems like a pretty simple for loop in any language.  Is there some aspect of async, or closures, that I am missing here?  Tons of questions exist about for loops not working as expected, but none in a jenkins-groovy-pipeline context, and certainly not for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, rather than delete I will post an answer in the event that it may help someone else in the future.  My issue was similar to [Iterate and print content of groovy closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145763/iterate-and-print-content-of-groovy-closures), though not exactly.  With help from that question, I just capture the current value of the index within the closure of the for loop and used that:

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= cypressRunners; i++) {
    def j = i // < ------- capture value within closure
    parallelStages["Cypress ${j}"] = {
        stage("Cypress ${j}") { 
            node("cypress-runner-agent") {
                echo "------------------ Cypress ${j} Stage ------------------"
                // more steps
            }
        }
    }
}
```